# Switch-Case for strings in Javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, switch-statement

So I have this problem with strings and switch-case, and I'll try to keep it as simple as possible.

Here event.keyCode has the value "65", and is the result of a keydown event of 'a' (using JQuery).

```
if (event.keyCode == "65") {
   alert("hmmmm");
}
```

That works, but:

```
switch (event.keyCode) {
   case '65':
      alert("Yay!");
      break;
}
```

That doesn't. However this will work:

```
switch ('65') {
   case '65':
      alert("Yay!");
      break;
}
```

And if I do this:

```
var t = '65';
switch (t) {
   case '65':
      alert("Yay!");
      break;
}
```

It works. And then I tried this:

```
var t = event.keyCode;
switch (t) {
   case '65':
      alert("Yay!");
      break;
}
```

But it fails!

So why does it match in the if-block at the beginning, but not for the switch-case?

Comment: What is your context testing ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.keyCode) is an integer, not a string.  When you use `==`, the conversion is done implicitly.  However, the switch uses the equivalent of `===`, which doesn't allow implicit conversions.  You can test this easily with:

```
switch (65) {
   case '65':
      alert("Yay!");
      break;
}
```

As expected, it does not alert.

This is stated in [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), 5th edition section 12.11 (switch statement).  The interpreter will enter a case statement if "`input` is equal to `clauseSelector` as defined by the === operator".  `input` is 65 (integer) and clauseSelector is '65' (string) in my above example, which are not `===`.

Comment: You're right, I'm used to things crashing when I compare (int == string). Thanks!

Comment: @2-Stroker, just switch directly on the number.  It may be faster too.