# More efficient way than using lots of else if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to find a better way to do this in Javascript:

```
if ( text === 'amy' ) {
var url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/amylikescats.html';
}
else if ( text === 'dave' ) {
var url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/daveshome.html';
}
else if ( text === 'steve' ) {
var url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/steve2.html';
}
else if ( text === 'jake' ) {
var url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/jakeeatstofu.html';
}
else {
var url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/noone.html';
}
```

Is there a more code efficient way of doing this?'

Comment: There are already some great answers below - this other stack overflow question is quite well referenced too and explains in a  bit more depth: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2573153/649979

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an object as a map:

```
var map = {
    "amy": 'http://www.mydomain.com/amylikescats.html',
    "dave": 'http://www.mydomain.com/daveshome.html',
    // etc
};

var text = "whatever";
var url = map[text] === undefined ? 'http://www.mydomain.com/noone.html' : map[text];
```

This will save you the maximum amount of repeated code, but if you also need to do other stuff than setting `url` a `switch` might be more appropriate.

Comment: If it's just a _mapping_ of keys to values, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

Switch statement!

```
var url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/noone.html';
switch(text) {
  case 'amy': url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/amylikescats.html';
  break;
  case 'dave': url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/daveshome.html';
  break;
  case 'steve': url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/steve2.html';
  break;
  case 'jake': url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/jakeeatstofu.html';
  break;
}
```

Now there is no need for a `default` clause because you've initialized `url` before the switch.

Otherwise you could add this:

```
default: url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/noone.html';
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Associative array:

```
var data = {
  amy: 'http://www.mydomain.com/amylikescats.html',
  dave: 'http://www.mydomain.com/daveshome.html',
  // etc... 
}
```

To use:

```
var url = data[text];
```

The `else` case can be replicate dby the non-existance of the item in the array, so expanding a bit:

```
var url = '';
if(!(text in data)){
    url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/daveshome.html';
}
else{
    url = data[text];
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript, they’re called objects.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - pedantic much? [This goog search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+associative+array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) indicates that the term "associative array" is quite often linked with javascript (judging by the ~400K results).

Comment: True true, and the concept of an associative array (if I understand properly) perfectly applies to JavaScript objects. It’s just not what they’re called in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Store the unique parts in a dictionary and then take it from there:

```
var map = {
    amy: "amylikescats",
    dave: "daveshome",
    steve: "steve2",
    jake: "jakeeatstofu"
};
var url = map[text];
if (!url) {
    url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/noone.html';
} else {
    url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/' + url + '.html';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object to hold the URLs for different values of text, and then use the `||` operator when assigning a value to `url` to use the fallback value if necessary.

```
var urlsForText = {
      'amy': 'http://www.mydomain.com/amylikescats.html',
     'dave': 'http://www.mydomain.com/daveshome.html',
    'steve': 'http://www.mydomain.com/steve2.html',
     'jake': 'http://www.mydomain.com/jakeeatstofu.html'
};

var url = urlsForText[text] || 'http://www.mydomain.com/noone.html';
```